# Cannot import Pytorch

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch, conda

While importing installed pytorch I am facing below issue

```
>>> import torch
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
        ctypes.CDLL(dll)
      File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
        self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible culprit by doing a Google search. Please read below-

---

It's a library load issue. More details at [#8836](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8836)

You probably have a broken `conda` right now. You can use a `standalone conda` from [here](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/misc/conda-execs/) to repair it:

```
standalone-conda.exe update -p C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 conda-package-handling
```

You should get the latest stable version, and the problems should go away.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9313#issuecomment-538609584).

Comment: I am unable  to update with it. I got another issue An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?

Comment: The simple thing I would suggest is reinstalling Anaconda3 and installing the latest stable version.